# Listening from Mongodb always and triggering

Tags: python, object-oriented, mongodb

I am using classes for the first time. In this program I want the object to run infinitely so that any change in the MongoDB will trigger the function and do the necessary processing.

I am little confused about the using of the `self`. Please give me feedback on my code.Thanks!

```
class first_level:




    def __init__(self):

        import pymongo
        connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")

        self.test_3_dec = connection.test_3_dec
        self.test1 = self.test_3_dec.test1
        self.test2 = self.test_3_dec.test2




    def listener_function(self):

        cursor = self.test2.find({},{"check_bit":True,"_id":True})

        for bit in cursor:
            if bit["check_bit"]==0:
                self.update_function(bit["check_bit"],bit["_id"])

    def update_function(self,value,value2):

        self.test1.insert({"_id":value2,"bit":value})

        self.test2.update({"_id":value2},{"$set":{"check_bit":1}})


obj = first()

while True:
    obj.listener_function()
```

Comment: Does your code actually work correctly to do what you want it to do?

Comment: @Phrancis Yes it works for protyping purpose for me

Comment: You don't need so many spaces between code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in doubt if your code actually works as you instantiate using `obj = first()`, but your class is named `first_level()`. This kind of indicates that either you've left out code, or you have broken code.

Anyway, here are some pointers for you:

- *Imports should go at start of file* – It's generally considere bad style to import stuff within classes or functions
- *The connection you create is forgotten* – You should store the connection, as it is killed when `__init__` is completed. You should use something like `self.connection = pymongo...`. If your code actually is working, then it is because the `self.testXXX` keeps it alive
- *Vertical space is good, but you've got too much* – The common policy is to have two blank lines in front off functions and classes, and single lines in front of different part you want to differentiate a little from other blocks.
- *Increase horizontal space* – After commas or colons you could benefit from adding spaces. Instead of `insert({"_id":value2,"bit":value})` do `insert({"_id": value2, "bit": value})`
- *Add comments and/or docstrings* – It is hard to read what your code actually does, and why it does it. This should be commented upon.
- *Avoid busy tight loops* – Doing `while True` with a single function not doing much, is a tight busy loop, and should usually be avoided. At least if doing it this way, you should add a sleep somewhere to avoid hogging resources.

### A better solution related to MongoDb

However instead of doing a busy loop with some code which I don't fully grasp, I believe you should look into the [monitoring](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/monitoring.html) of the mongodb. This would allow you to get notified when commands are executed against the mongodb.

At least, that is how I read the documentation, with little knowledge of mongodb. And this pattern of adding a listener, and then waiting for it to respond is a bettern pattern rather than busy waiting and changing stuff to check if it is alive.

Comment: Hey @holroy sorry for the first mistake - my class is `first` only. I should use the import at the begining and connection in between of the class?